# Java - Optimized calling of multiple commands

Tags: java, performance, optimization, command, command-line-arguments

**Question**
What is the most efficient way of calling multiple commands from a Java program?

**Background**
My team and I have been tasked with creating a program that eventually calls a series (anywhere from one hundred to ten thousand, or possibly more) of commands on a UNIX system. The commands are not simple, built-in commands, but rather are part of a software that has already been installed on the machine. Because these commands are fairly work-intensive and performance is a key factor in the success of our software, I have been researching the most efficient way of calling multiple commands from Java. Unfortunately, I have yet to find a single post, question, or forum that has discussed the calling of multiple commands from a performance perspective.

**Knowledge**
I am very familiar with IO in Java, and have worked with the `Runtime`, `Process`, and `ProcessBuilder` classes before.

**What I'm Looking for**
I am looking for a high or low-level (pseudo-only, if low-level, please) explanation of how to best optimize the calling of multiple commands from within a Java program. I am unable to post our code on the web, but I do not believe that our code is necessary, in this situation. For sake of ease, feel free to assume that the command we are calling is `cmd`, which takes arguments `-a arg0 -b arg1`. It may be helpful to know that the command strings are generated earlier in the program and do not change based on the results of other calls. It may also help to know that the results of all of the calls will be strings that are to be added to an `ArrayList`.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: By command you mean separate executable?

Comment: Yes, the software that we are calling is ImageMagick, but we cannot use their Java library

Comment: Please precise your need of controls: each command should be controlled or a batch of commands in a script file (bash) may be a solution?

Comment: @Aubin - If by "controlled" you mean to say that the other commands being called are dependent upon the results of the previous commands, and by "batch of commands" you mean a pre-compiled list of commands to be called, then the answer is the latter (batch of commands)

Comment: Why not use shell scripts? The time will be spent by the commands themselves (i.e. the image processing), and the way you launch them won't change much (if anything).

Comment: @Joe - To clarify further, the commands that we are running are from a separate executable, but, as ImageMagick is already installed, we will be calling the commands directly.

Comment: Do you want the commands to run sequentially, or can some be done in parallel with each other?

Comment: @JBNizet - Do you mean to advise the use of shell scripts for the entire program, or simply the calling of a shell script to make all of the command calls?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - If running them in parallel will increase their performance then running them in parallel would be preferable.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel I suggest putting most of your effort into optimizing the plan for running the commands - what can you usefully do in parallel without overloading your machine? The details of whether you run a single script or manage them directly from Java are unlikely to have much effect on performance.

Comment: I mean for the entire program. I don't think Java is the best tool to invoke shell commands. There are multiple scripting languages that are better for this kind of tasks.

Comment: I've even sometimes used parallel make for this sort of thing - it provides an easy way to restart after failure part way through the work, as well as managing the number of activities that run in parallel, and which ones depend on each other.

Comment: @JBNizet - I do agree with you, but this aspect of the program is part of a larger software. Regardless, I believe that this solution may be helpful to others, so you should post this as an answer and provide an explanation of your reasoning and I will upgrade it.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - Can you post your solution as an answer? I would prefer to keep the comments on the question, itself, as minimal as possible, and would like to continue discussion on your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main issue here is parallel running of as many commands as can usefully be run in parallel. That will often make a far bigger difference in performance than any difference in exactly how the commands are managed.

Generally, I agree with the idea of using a script of some sort, and having Java directly run only the script's interpreter.

In particular, in this sort of situation, I have sometimes used parallel make. The makefile can specify the commands to run, and any dependencies between them. For example, in a situation in which I needed to do hundreds of simulations, I had rules that made the raw simulation reports each depend on a simulation control file, and the processed reports depend on the raw reports.

Parallel make can make it easy and efficient to resume work after a failure without redoing all the work that was successfully completed. It can also manage limiting parallelism to a reasonable number of threads.

Comment: Would you say that using parallel make would be a better option that creating multiple `thread` objects?

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel If you drive each command individually and can have significant parallelism you will need a lot of threads to consume the standard out and standard error from each command. I do not recommend driving a large number of commands directly from Java. Whether you use make or some other script, I think you should delegate managing the commands to some script language.

Comment: Incidentally, you can create the script from Java, rather than editing it manually, if that is more convenient.

Comment: Very much so! Thanks for your continued support! :)

Comment: +1 for parallel techniques, important on modern machines with many processors.